# Delete dial rule in Asterisk via AMI

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I'm running Asterisk 11.4.0, and I've got access to it via AMI.
I've got a line like this in my [default] context in extensions.conf.

```
exten => 12345,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@0041905093,30,r)
```

So, i have mask (12345) and I need to delete a dial rule, belonging to the mask. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this:
If you want to remove extension A from context B, you need write CLI command (using "action" = "command") like this:

```
dialplan remove extension A@B
```